# How to display category image in topmenu navigation in magento 2

Tags: megamenu

I m using [this extension](https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-mega-menu-extension.html) for mega menu, i need to display a category image for every menu item.

[image]

Comment: check this link you can use it:http://www.catgento.com/2017/03/20/magento-2-display-category-image-in-navigation-menu/

Comment: i will check and update u @rakesh

Comment: @divya sekar Add images in static blocks and than select that block from category. see this link : https://www.screencast.com/t/Sslsvk9u8

Comment: @Sanjay Gohil   i was tried it already i add static image https://prnt.sc/n1gqva by your way  but i  want   to do with category image

Comment: i tried this link  nothing  happens @rakesh

Comment: you have admin side upload image? @SanjayGohil given scrrenshot

Comment: @rakesh, there is no upload image in admin side, they can add statically add a image in cms block  i already tried that option  but  i need to show dynamic image from  category image https://prnt.sc/n1rpn6

Comment: @divyasekar you can menu block file menu.php file in customize coding

Comment: i was done it @rakesh thanks